# Inject validator java ee

Tags: java, java-ee

Когда внедряю `validator`, компилятор подчеркивает его "желтым" и пишет: Неудовлетворенная зависимость, отсутствуют компоненты соответствующие точке внедрения зависимости. И в итоге валидация не работает. Подскажите чего не хватает? Инструменты: NetBeans, GlassFish, Maven.

Класс где внедряю зависимость:

```
import static com.mycompany.validationofcdibean.BeanString.isValid;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

@WebServlet(name = "ServletStart", urlPatterns = {
    "/start"
})
public class ServletStart extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    ValidatorFactory vf;

    Validator validator;
    int i;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        BeanString bs = new BeanString(request.getParameter("firstName"), request.getParameter("lastName"));
        validator=vf.getValidator();
        i = isValid(bs, validator); //вот здесь возвращает ноль
        request.setAttribute("fnameMess", i);

    }
```

Класс Bean:

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class BeanString {

    public BeanString() {}

    public BeanString(String fname, String lname) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    @NotNull
    private String fname;
    @NotNull
    private String lname;

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "BeanString{" + "fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname + '}';
    }

    public static int isValid(Object str, Validator validator) {
        int i;
        Set < ConstraintViolation < Object»valid = validator.validate(str);
        i = valid.size();
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: `validator` наверное следует получать не через `@Inject`, а в коде в нужном месте: `validator = vf.getValidator()`

Comment: пробовал, возвращает в методе isValid, ноль

Comment: Что значит в `isValid` ноль? После этого `validator = vf.getValidator()`, `validator != null`, а в `isValid` - `null`? Тогда где-то не там извлекаете validator. Надо получить его перед использованием в isValid: `validator = vf.getValidator(); i = isValid(bs, validator);`

Comment: так и сделал. возвращает ноль, всмысле все данные валидны(i=0). В методе isValid возвращается кол-во ошибок.

Comment: С `validator`-ом теперь всё нормально. А как работает Ваш `isValid` это уже другая история. Раз ноль, значит всё нормально, никаких нарушений нет. Могу только предположить, что на самом деле хотели вызвать `BeanString.isValid(bs, validator)`, а получился вызов  не показанного здесь метод `isValid` из `ServletStart`

Comment: И перенесите `Validator validator` и `int i` из полей класса в локальные переменные метода `doPost`. Единственная полезная мысль на которую навёл поток слов из ответа ниже. Действительно разные запросы будут конфликтовать из-за этих общих переменных.

Comment: спасибо. дальше буду разбираться сам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) А кто в твоем случае обрабатывает инжект?

Использование javax.inject подразумевает какой-нибудь ИоС контейнер, который будет создавать бины и инжектить в них зависимости (в твоем случае я рекомендую использовать Spring (MVC)).

2) Ты серьезно намерен использовать не финальные поля не синглтон объектов в веб контроллере (сервлете)  ?

```
Validator validator;
int i;
```

Представь, что к тебе зайдет 30 запросов одновременно. Так как на всё веб приложение создается по одному контроллеру (сервлету) каждого типа (синглтон), то все эти запросы пойдут в один контроллер в один метод и работать будут с одними переменными. поведение программы не предсказуемо.

3) Кто реализует апи валидации?

javax.validation это такое же апи как и инжект с компанией. следовательно, для работы его тоже кто-то должен реализовывать.

**Выводы**:

1. либо подключи ИоС контейнер (можете реализовать свой) либо забудь об
   инжекшине
2. посмотри курс по многопоточности. веб приложение это многопоточное приложение. с глобальными переменными надо быть крайне акуратным
3. если хочешь использовать валидатор подключи его
   реализацию, или реализуй сам.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. пойду читать про ИоС